# Footer pops up halfway up page

Tags: html, css, footer

Firstly let me say that this is my first post, and also my first website which I am building for school. I am only into my second week of html/css learning, so my knowledge is pretty basic.

Now here is my problem: My CSS works for my footer on one page, but on the other the footer pops up halfway in the page. I've went through and checked one page's code to the other, and I do not see any difference. Here is my CSS code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* temporary background color for testing purposes  */
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, el, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;}
body {
  line-height: 1;}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;}
  /* My Styles */
body {
font-family: Arial, Hevetical, sans-serif;
font-size: 100%;
background-color: blue;
width: 80%
border:dashed;
border-color:#FF0004;
margin: 0 auto;
}
header{
 padding: 3em;
 height: 330px;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: lightblue; 
 position: relative;
}
nav{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}
nav a{
 padding: .25em 5em;
}
section{
 padding: 3em;
}
footer{
 padding: 3em;
 background-color: lightblue;
 text-align: center;
}
aside{
 padding:3em;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}
h1, h2, h3{
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}
h1{
 font-size: 250%;
}
h1 a{
 text-decoration:none;
}
h2{
 font-size: 150%;
}
h3{
 font-size: 80%;
}
.col-1-2{
 width: 32%;
 float: left;
}
.col-2-3{
 width: 65%;
 float: left;
}
.cleafix:before, .clearfix:after{
 content:"";
 display:table;
}
.clearfix:after{
 clear:both;
}
.clearfix{
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Crystal Coast Theater</title>
<link href="../CSS/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<header style="text-align:center">
<a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/index.html"><h1> Crystal Coast Theater.
</h1></a>
<nav style="text-align:center">
<a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/index.html" >Home</a>
<a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/event.html">Events</a>
<a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/ticket.html">Tickets</a>
<a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/contact.html">Contact us</a>
</nav>
</header>
<div class="container cleatfix">
<aside class="col-1-2">
<h2>Upcoming events:</h2>
<p><span class="emphasis">May 22&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;June 8:</span>&nbsp; Daring Last Days of Blackbeard</p>
<p><span class="emphasis">June 11&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;June 29:</span>&nbsp; Ghost Stories of the Crystal Coast</p>
<p><span class="emphasis">July 3&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;July 20:</span>&nbsp; Beach Rental</p>
<p><span class="emphasis">July 23&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;August 10:</span>&nbsp; The Siege of Fort Macon</p>
</aside>
<section class="col-2-3"> 
<h2>Your Down East Playhouse</h2>
<p>The Crystal Coast Theater is located in downtown Moorehead City. It features local talent performing in both renowned plays and in works written by some of the Crystal Coast’s own talented playwrights.</p>
<br>
<p>The Crystal Coast Theater also offers educational performances that bring to life the history and culture of the 85 miles of coastline that are favorite destinations for tourists.</p>
<br>
<p>Check out our upcoming events and make plans to come and see one of our shows.</p>
</section>
</div>
<footer style="text-align:center">
<small>Copyright &copy; 2015 ~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~ ~~~~~</small>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my HTML code for the page is question:

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-dark_nemesis

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle for both pages?

Comment: I'll be honest, seeing as I am so new to this, I have no idea what a jsfiddle is. I also am not trying to use too advanced of coding as I am not sure if my teacher would allow me using it.*Edit* I googled jsfiddle, and for a jsfiddle website. I placed my CSS and my HTML codes into the approprate boxes, pressed run, and I received the same results.

Comment: Hmm, yeah i had no idea about this myself a few years ago. https://jsfiddle.net/ Simple paste your code in the html and css sections so i can take a look at both, because at the moment, the preview on here, is showing both styling and html separately and the footer seems to be in place. Run the code and save, then comment the link, do this for both pages.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle URL:  https://jsfiddle.net/x3hztyq2/   https://jsfiddle.net/62vuay8v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. https://jsfiddle.net/x3hztyq2/1/

```
footer {
padding: 3em;
background-color: lightblue;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 70em;
```

To keep it simple so your teacher doesn't get suspicious, i have used basic positioning. I added the 'position: absolute;' to keep it's position on track when moving it, and to move it i used 'top: 70em;' Using top is like having the top of the page push the footer towards the bottom, and the position element keeps it in place. With the 'em' as measurements, it makes it more responsive when it comes to different screen sizes, i only added that because i have a habbit of it :)

Comment: Thank you! I will add this code to my CSS. I am however curious, is there anything that you read in either my CSS or my HTML codes that would make one work, while the other doesn't? Being new to all of this makes me curious as to why it worked with one page, but not the other.

Comment: I can't make out any difference, it's strikes my curiosity aswell, it could just be something we have both missed, however, i found this going through the code. <p">3411 Arendell Street</p> The opening tag has a quotation mark, that's one bug you can remove :)